# How to read parameter from .txt file in bash

Tags: bash, nmap

I want to use an `nmap` script to convert ASN -> IP ranges

So the nmap script is used like that,

```
nmap --script targets-asn --script-args ragets-asn.asn=12345
```

This command return the IP ranges in `12345` ASN.

I have a `list.txt` with multiple ASN.
I want to run the `nmap` command for all the ASNs in the `list.txt` file

Bash is preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for asn in $(cat list.txt)
do
        nmap --script targets-asn --script-args targets-asn.asn=$asn 2>&1|sed -e "1,/$asn/ d"|egrep -v 'WARNING|Nmap'|awk '{print $2}'
done
```

Some details:

The for loop will read the list.txt file one line at a time and execute the nmap with the asn provided.

The "2>&1" tells nmap to send both stdout and stderr to the pipe (|)

The sed command cases the command to output only data after the $asn match (remove the nmap header and other info messages that are not needed)

The egrep removes some more of the messages we don't want.

The awk command prints only the IPs without the "|" "_" tree symbols

Comment: Just a note, using all three `sed`, `grep`, and `awk` is really not necessary as `sed` (or `awk`) alone is powerful enough to handle final filtering.